# Method with parameter doesn't work in return

Tags: typescript, methods, return

I'm verifying some conditions to return a boolean result, but I see that the method "usuarioRelacionado" is not being called.
If I don't put a parameter in it, it works.

```
private possuiPermissaoVisualizarProcesso(processo: ProcessoPorNumeroEOrgaoConsultaResultadoWs): boolean {
    return this.possuiPermissao({role: permissoes.ACESSO_TODOS_PROCESSOS}) || (this.usuarioRelacionado(processo) && this.possuiPermissao({role: permissoes.PROCESSO_VISUALIZAR}));
  }

  private usuarioRelacionado(processo: ProcessoPorNumeroEOrgaoConsultaResultadoWs): boolean {
    const codigoUsuario = PermissaoService.getUsuarioLogado().codigoUsuario;
    return (processo.responsaveis
      && processo.responsaveis.some((responsavel: ResponsavelEntidadeWs) => responsavel.codigoUsuario === codigoUsuario))
      || (processo.gruposUsuarios
        && processo.gruposUsuarios.some((grupo: GrupoUsuarioWs) =>
          grupo.responsaveis
          && grupo.responsaveis.some((responsavel: ResponsavelEntidadeWs) => responsavel.codigoUsuario === codigoUsuario)
        ));
  }
```

Comment: If it's not called, it means that `this.possuiPermissao({role: permissoes.ACESSO_TODOS_PROCESSOS})` is truthy, and the rest of the condition doesn't need to be evaluated, since `true || whatever` will always be true.

Comment: See MDN: [Logical Operators / Short-circuit evaluation
Section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation).